# WIX Heat Parameters to Set Properties

Tags: wix, windows-installer, console-application, wix3.8

I am new to Wix Toolkit. I am creating an .msi for a console application. Below is my one of my line which is generated using heat command :

```
 <Component Id="cmp2B116558C64AF876AD223372FA4B8DFF" Directory="dir99DE416F55C8960850D5A4FCA3758AD4" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
        <File Id="fil19E0EEE3E5D0208523116CAFE9E9B06E" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\App.config" />
      </Component>
```

I just need that **PUT-GUID-HERE** to be get set automatically. Is there anything that i need to change in my heat command. Below is my heat command which i am using.

```
heat dir "C:\Users\rp5026921\Documents\Project\Automation Testing\SourceCode\MeridianAutomation\bin\Release" -cg ComponentsGroup -out "C:\Users\rp5026921\Documents\Project\Automation Testing\SourceCode\MeridianAutomationSetUp\MeridianAutomationComponents.wxs" –gg
```

One more issue is that, i am having app.config in my console application. In that i need to change certain values after installing the .msi. But after installation when i go inside the folder its not allowing me to edit the app.config file.

Comment: for the second part, are you trying to edit the file using WiX after the install?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right command line option but just move the "-gg" before the "-out" command line option as shown below.

-gg : Generate guids now. All components are given a guid when heat is run.
-ag : Auto generate component guids at compile time, e.g. set Guid="*".

```
heat dir "C:\Users\rp5026921\Documents\Project\Automation Testing\SourceCode\MeridianAutomation\bin\Release" -cg ComponentsGroup -gg -out "C:\Users\rp5026921\Documents\Project\Automation Testing\SourceCode\MeridianAutomationSetUp\MeridianAutomationComponents.wxs"
```